# psycopg2 register_composite from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

is it possible to somehow use function [register_composite](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.register_composite) from psycopg2, when i am using sqlalchemy to connect to postgresql database?

My problem is that I want SQLAlchemy to handle custom composite type that i created in postgresql like this:

```
CREATE TYPE card AS (value int, suit text);
```

Sqlalchemy returns me values of this type as an string and I would like to somhow learn sqlalchemy my new type. If found some information about creating custom composite types in SQL alchemy ORM, but I am using just SQLAlechemy Core API (not ORM) and somebody on sqlalchemy IRC told me that psycopg should do it for me.

I would be happy with any advice, that would solve this.

Thank you
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so, I will answer myself :)

I have not found any way how to access to method register_composite of psycopg2 from sqlalchemy core api. But i am able to register new type via psycopg2 methods new_type and register_adapter. Tutorial can be found [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax).
This methods allows you to register mapping from sql representation to python class and the other way.

From SQLAlechemy connection you can access these methods like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
e = create_engine("postgresql://xxx:xxx@localhost:5432/db")
c = e.connect()
c.dialect.dbapi.extensions.register_adapter
c.dialect.dbapi.extensions.new_type
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the psycopg2 function `register_composite` from sqlalchemy but you have to

```
import psycopg2.extras
```

yourself, then with your connection object `c` from

```
c = e.connect()
```

just do

```
psycopg2.extras.register_composite('card', c.connection, globally=True)
```

You have to use `c.connection` because

```
>>> hasattr(c.connection, 'cursor')
True
```